# Include SSCCE.ORG contents in an instruction page somewhere

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, help

It's not a question, just a suggestion:
moderators, can you put the contents of http://sscce.org/ into stackoverflow and introduce them as law such as how to ask questions?

Comment: Pretty sure this has already been implemented.

Comment: Can you give me a link ?

Comment: There is mention of it here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that page is going anywhere any time soon, so I don't think we necessarily need to copy the content here.  We also already link to that page in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and in one of our "off-topic" close reasons.

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

I think that makes the SSCCE page as official as it needs to be, considering we already have our own [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: I always thought that site was authored by some [se] insider. But checking the WHOIS doesn't match any SE user. Maybe it's [one of these guys](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22david+minter%22&tbm=isch).

Comment: @brasofilo That page was authored by [Andrew Thompson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson).